# Topological Transitivity and Existence of Non-surjective Map

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $T : X \to X$ be a continuous map that is **topologically transitive**. The history of topological transitivity is a long one and many authors opt for [different and independent definitions](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_transitivity#Topological_transitivity_versus_the_existence_of_a_dense_orbit). I have given two such definitions below:

> **Definition 1**. For every pair of non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$, there is a non-negative integer $n$ such that $f^n(U) \cap V \neq \emptyset$. 
> **Definition 2**. There is a point $x \in X$ such that the forward-orbit $\{T^n(x)\}_{n \geq 0}$ is dense in $X$.

My question concerns the hypotheses we can impose on $X$ to guarantee that it is surjection. From previous discussion on the forum, it is known that under **Definition 1**, $X$ being compact implies that $T$ is surjective. We also have examples (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601034/in-a-non-compact-metric-space-topological-transitivity-need-not-imply-onto?rq=1) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290528/in-a-non-compact-metric-space-topological-transitivity-need-not-imply-onto)) of non-compact spaces $X$ with non-surjective topologically transitive maps $T$. My questions are mainly about the case of **Definition 2**. Specifically,

> 1. Under **Definition 2**, does there exist a **compact** metric space $(X, d)$ with non-surjective topological transitive $T$?
> 2. Under **Definition 2**, does there exist a **complete** metric space $(X, d)$ with non-surjective topological transitive $T$?
> 3. Under **Definition 1**, does there exist a **complete** metric space $(X, d)$ with non-surjective topological transitive $T$?

If such a system exists for (1.), then it would be a system for (2.). The last question is a weakening of hypothesis about the result under Definition 1. Any observations, hints, and answers would be appreciated.

**Note:** Definition 1 and Definition 2 are equivalent when $(X, d)$ is complete, separable, and contains no isolated points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume Definition 2. There exists a compact metric space $(X,d)$ with non-surjective topological transitive $T$. Let  $X=\{0\}\cup\{2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual metric and $T(x)=x/2$ for each $x\in X$.

On the other hand, if $T$ is a topologically transitive continuous map on a Hausdorff compact space $X$ without isolated points then there is a point $x\in X$ such that a set $X’=\{T^n(x)\}_{n \geq 1}$ is dense in $X$. Then the set $T(X)$ contains $X’$, so $T(X)$ is a dense. Since $T(X)$ is compact, it is closed in $X$. So $T(X)=X$.

Also there exists a completely metrizable space $X$ without isolated points and a topologically transitive non-surjective continuous map $T$ on $X$. Indeed, let $X_0$ be the unit circle $\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$ endowed with the usual topology and $T$ be a rotation of $X$ into an angle $\phi$ such that $\phi/\pi$ is irrational. Pick any point $x\in X_0$ and put $X=X_0\setminus \{T^n(x)\}_{n<0}$. Then the space $X$ is a $G_\delta$ set of a completely metrizable space, so it is metrizable, $\{T^n(x)\}_{n \geq 1}$ is dense in $X$, but $x\not\in T(X)$. Remark that the map $T$ is topologically transitive also with respect to Definition 1.